# Combine OneToMany + FetchType.LAZY + LazyCollection + jackson-datatype-hibernate to return size in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate

I was wondering if the following is possible.

I've got some parent class.

```java
@Entity
public class Parent {

  private String name;

  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

And obviously my children class.

```java
@Entity
public class Child {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonBackReference
  private Parent parent;

}
```

I use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate to make sure lazy loading really works and jackson does not include the whole list. I register the module using a bean.

```java
@Bean
public Hibernate5Module datatypeHibernateModule() {
  return new Hibernate5Module();
}
```

It all works as expected. Currently my JSON looks like this.

```json
{
  "name": "my name",
  "children": null
}
```

In my frontend application I'd like to show the parent `name` and the number of `children`. Is it possible to return the size of `children` without using a custom query?

```json
{
  "name": "my name",
  "children": 3141 <- include the size here
}
```

In the backend I can easily use `parent.getChildren().size()` which creates an additional request to the database.

```sql
select count() ...
```

Can I somehow access this information in the frontend application? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking if it's possible to know the size of a list without fetching its elements?

Comment: Also, have you actually seen a `select count() ... ` query after calling `List.size()`? That would be surprising

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know the size of a list without fetching its elements. That's the whole point of lazy loading and `LazyCollection`. The `count` sql statement is only executed when I call the `size()` method. If you enable trace and debug logging for hibernate and BasicBinder you can really see the `count` statement. Now I want to know if it is possible to send the size to my frontend application without creating a custom query and maybe a custom projection.

Comment: If it really works like that, then the easiest solution would be to return a DTO with an `int children` property which your service would populate with `getChildren().size()`. I don't think it gets any easier than that

Comment: That's what I thought and I was wondering if there is a more "already built-into the framework" solution that I'm not aware of. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can run this JPQL query:

```
select p.name, count(c)
join Person p left join p.children c
group by p.name
```